# $m(E) \geq 0$ instead of $m(E) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

There's this lemma in Real Analysis by Royden and Fitzpatrick that goes:

> Lemma 16: Let $E$ be a bounded measurable set of real numbers. Suppose there is a bounded countably infinite set of real numbers $\Lambda$ for which the collection of translates of $E$, $\{\lambda + E\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$, is disjoint. Then $m(E) = 0$.

There's this claim in the proof that I do not understand.

[image]

Isn't this supposed to be $\geq 0$ rather than $> 0$? I don't really see how positive numbers add up to zero...

If no (this is), thanks, and ignore what follows.

If yes (this isn't), how does $m(E)=0$ follow? If $m(E) = 0.0001$, $0.0001+0.0001+\dots = \infty$, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a mistake. I suspect at some point the idea was a proof by contradiction ("Suppose $m(E) > 0$, then ...") and that was then changed, but the "$m(E) > 0$" remained.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer ! I like your BOTD ways :))

Comment: What does "BOTD" mean?

Comment: @DanielFischer Benefit of the Doubt. As in, you found away to make R&F right. Lol

Comment: Thanks for the expansion. Well, not right. A reasonable possible explanation of the origin of the mistake.

Comment: Oh, that's what I meant to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, $m(E) \geq 0$. Alternatively, you could interpret it as a proof by contradiction where the assumption that is made is that $m(E) > 0$. I'm pretty sure it is just a typo though.

**Added Later:** You can check the [errata](http://www.math.umd.edu/~pmf/err130405.pdf) to see if it is indeed a typo. I don't have the page number so I can't do it myself.

Comment: And I like your BOTD ways @MichaelAlbanese :))